# Calculate the contour integral of a complex trigonometric function (sinz)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let $C$ be the unit circle in the complex plane with positive orientation. Calculate
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{sin^3z}$$

Solution: $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{sin^3z}=\bigg(sinz=0\Rightarrow z=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow z_1=0\in|z|=1\bigg)=\frac{2\pi i}{(3-1)!}(1)''\bigg|_{z_1=0}=0$

I am beginner in complex analysis, can you, please, check the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. That integral is equal to$$2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin^3z}\right)=\pi i.$$To see why, note that, since $\sin^3(z)=z^3-\frac12z^5+\cdots$, if$$\frac1{\sin^3z}=\frac a{z^3}+\frac bz+\cdots,$$we have\begin{align}1&=\left(z^3-\frac12z^5+\cdots\right)\left(\frac a{z^3}+\frac bz+\cdots\right)\\&=\left(1-\frac12z^2+\cdots\right)(a+bz^2+\cdots)\\&=a+\left(a-\frac12b\right)z^2+\cdots\end{align}So, $a=1$ and, since $a-\frac12b=0$, $b=\frac12$. And $b=\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin^3z}\right)$.

Comment: How should I know when in complex contour integrals I must use residues?

Comment: becouse the similar task : $$\int_{|z-2|=3}\frac{e^z}{z^3(z-1)}=J_1+J_2=\frac{2\pi i}{(3-1)!}\bigg(\frac{e^z}{z-1}\bigg)''\bigg|_{z=0} + 2\pi i \frac{e^z}{z^3}\bigg|_{z=1}=-5\pi i +2\pi e i=\pi i(2e-5)$$ is correct (according to answers in book:) )

Comment: When you see no other way of doing it.

Comment: What is the difference between first task and the task from my comment?

Comment: Because in that task you were integrating a function of the form $\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^n}$. That's not the case here.

Comment: Last question : When to use the Cauchy formula for integrating complex functions, and when should integrals be calculated using residues?

Comment: You use Cauchy's formula for integrals of the type that I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. This self-education due to the quarantine killing me(

Comment: I'm glad I could help.